# GeoMesa: Polygon creation fails with some coordinates

Tags: geoserver, geotools, geomesa

I am creating a polygon as a geom attribute in a SimpleFeature, and testing it with various geospatial coordinates, but I am finding that some coordinates work with POLYGON and others raise an exception. For example, this bounding box in South Korea fails:

```
Invalid xz value from geometry/time: POLYGON ((35.709649 128.188477, 35.708649 128.188477, 35.708649 128.188201, 35.709649 128.188201, 35.709649 128.188477))
```

but using the same code and specifying some coordinates in Italy works fine:

```
POLYGON((44.751610 9.997559, 44.750610 9.997559, 44.750610 9.997001, 44.751610 9.997001, 44.751610 9.997559))
```

There are others around the globe that work fine also, but South Korea in particular consistently fails. Does anybody know why this is and how I might stabilize the behavior so that it works consistently?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoMesa assumes that the points are defined in longitude-latitude order.  I believe the polygon you have defined for South Korea is written in latitude-longitude order.

If you reverse the coordinates, it should work.

Comment: This website is handy for visualizing WKT polygons: http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html

Comment: You are absolutely right sir, had the order reversed. Thank you! Emilio - thank you also for the link looks very useful. Thanks again guys